# Html/javascript: Unable to disable Textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Not really sure how to phrase the question but I have created a function where if a button is disabled, the textbox below should also be disabled, but it's not. Here's the code:

```
<script>
function Play(){
if (document.getElementById("high").value > document.getElementById("low").value){ 
document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;}
else {document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("ErrorForPlay").innerHTML = "Numbers Wrong."}
}
</script> //this script checks to see if the higher number is less than the lower number. Will be disabled if so.

<br>
<button id="myBtn" onclick="Play()">Play</button>
<span id="ErrorForPlay"> </span>

<!--assume that the button on top is always disabled-->

GUESS: <!--But the textbox does not disable-->
<br>
<Input type="number" id="guess" onclick="dataValidationG()" onchange="dataValidationG()"> </Input>
<button id="submit">Enter Guess</button>

<script>
function dataValidationG(){
if (document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;){
document.getElementById("guess").disabled = true;}
else {document.getElementById("guess").disabled = false;}

//script to check. If Button "myBtn" is disabled, the text should also disable if not, the text should be enabled.
}
</script>
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the javascript but I can't place where did I go wrong/what's missing. (I'm also only allowed to do everything under 1 html file.)

Comment: one thing, the condition if (document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;) has to have double == or triple ===

Comment: call `dataValidationG()` in `Play()` function - else condition as well to check the if `myBtn` was `disabled` or not. Also, change your `if` condition to `if (document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled) {})` in `dataValidationG()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your if statement conditions, you are using `=` and not `==`.

And thanks to JavaScript being such a nice programming language, it doesn't throw a syntax error, but instead sets the value inside the if statement condition!

So just replace the `=` with `==` inside your if statement conditions.